# How to extract the text from a cell in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I created a Student class and a ListView in MainActivity. Here is MainActivity:

```
Context context;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<Student> lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista= new ArrayList<>();
    context=this;
    Student cursant = new Student("Smith","Ben",14);
    Student cursant2 = new Student("White","Jack",21);
    Student cursant3 = new Student("Stewart","Matt",33);
    lista.add(cursant);
    lista.add(cursant2);
    lista.add(cursant3);
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,lista));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            String selected =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNume)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("name",selected);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {
ArrayList<Student> current_objects;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Student> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.current_objects=objects;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return current_objects.size();
}

@Override
public Student getItem(int position) {
    return current_objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public class Holder{
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    Button button;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    final View rowView;
    rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
    holder.tv1=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNume);
    holder.tv2=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrenume);
    holder.tv3=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVarsta);

    final Student current_cursant = current_objects.get(position);
    holder.tv1.setText(current_cursant.getNume());
    holder.tv2.setText(current_cursant.getPrenume());
    holder.tv3.setText(String.valueOf(current_cursant.getVarsta()));

    holder.button=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    holder.button.setTag(position);

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer index=(Integer)v.getTag();
            current_objects.remove(index.intValue());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

}

I created Main2Activity and I would like to display the name (in Main2Activity) when one cell of the listview is pressed. I am not sure about the ClickListener.

Comment: show code of the layout also.

Answer (score 0):

***First try this***:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

*If this is giving you the correct result then Just add the Intent code replacing the Toast statement.*

Answer (score 0):

Your `onItemClick` part seems correct so I guess the problem must be on how to display the text on Main2Activity.

You have already passed the intent and started the Main2Activity.

Now you just need to receive the intent and show it.

Suppose you have a textView in Main2Activiy with id textView1 then you will receive the intent as follows:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }

        String name= extras.getString("name");

        TextView textView = (TextView) 
                findViewById(R.id.textView1);       
        textView.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Student student = (Student)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        // do whatever you want with student object
    }
});
```